# Unable to center text inside an absolute positioned div

Tags: html, css

I have 2 divs, one called info-holder and the other called info-content.

Info-holder has `relative` positioning whereas info content has `absolute` positioning.

The content contains (or will eventually contain) paragraph and heading elements, but they are aligned left, when I want them to be aligned center.

Any idea how I can fix this?

Here is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/2egL00y5/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `width: 100%` to the elements:

```
.info-content {
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    width: 100%;
}
```

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2egL00y5/1/

**EDIT:**

If you don't need the `position: absolute`, the only style that you need to apply is:

```
.info-content {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Removing also the styles in `h1`.

FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/2egL00y5/4/

Comment: Improved on this by making the elements in my absolute positioned div relative to it, so i dont have to make their width 100%. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

```
.info-holder {
    position: relative;
    height: 420px;
    max-height: 420px;
    width: 29%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.info-content {
    text-align: center;
}
h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

alternative -  `transform: translate`

```css
.info-holder {
 position: relative;
 height: 420px;
 max-height: 420px;
 width: 29%;
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 0;
 text-align: center;
 background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.info-content {
 position: absolute; left: 50%;
 text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, 0);
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
h1 {
 margin: 0 auto; 
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="info-holder">
    <div class="info-content">
         <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```